# OS X cmake can't find PythonLibs 3.4

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, cmake

python and python3 are installed in OS X Yosemite via Homebrew, but cmake fails to find PythonLibs 3, only 2:

---

CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 3.4)
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonInterp REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs 3.4 REQUIRED)
```

get:

```
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/local/bin/python3.4 (found suitable version "3.4.3", minimum required is "3.4")
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/libpython3.4.dylib (found version "2.7.6"
```

---

CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 3.4)
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonInterp 3.4 REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs 3.4 REQUIRED)
```

get:

```
Could NOT find PythonLibs: Found unsuitable version "2.7.6", but required
is at least "3.4" (found PYTHON_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND)
```

---

Then I added this to cmake lists:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m)
```

and even copied that directories to `/usr/lib`, and then got:

```
Could NOT find PythonLibs: Found unsuitable version "2.7.6", but required
is at least "3.4" (found /usr/lib/libpython3.4.dylib)
```

that looks weird.

Comment: same problem with cmake on Windows, specially this line is a stupid error message: `(found suitable version "3.4.3", minimum required is "3.4")`

Answer (score 1):

It appears the correct version of Python is found in your `CMake` configuration, but locations of the libraries also needs to be set. Depending on your installation/configuration the location of the libraries might vary, although in the configuration you'll want something similar:

```
PYTHON_LIBRARIES=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/libpython3.4m.dylib
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m
```

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPythonLibs.html

Comment: It doesn't look line an universal solution, however it worked fine. Now I decided to do it using python3 setuptools instead of cmake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to the libraries in your "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" environment variable. In this way, CMake will know where to look for them. This may happen with multiple python installations or when it is installed in a non standard location. This should solve it:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

The CMake command "INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES" is only for headers (aka. /usr/include).

-> If my solution doesn't work, make sure you have python-devel installed: [how to install python-devel in Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578106/how-to-install-python-devel-in-mac-os)