# how to install python-devel in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, python-2.7

brew and port does not provide `python-devel`. 
How can I install it in Mac OS. 
Is there an equivalent in Mac OS?

Comment: You might have not installed **Xcode** on your system prior to installing Python-Devel. 
Try installing Xcode first and then refer [here](http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/) in order to do so on your MAC OS X. @user77005

Comment: Why 2.7 and not Python 3? And since Python is free software, you can always compile it from its source code...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install the Python development headers on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931331/how-to-install-the-python-development-headers-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 28):

If you install Python using `brew`, the relevant headers are already installed for you.

In other words, you don't need `python-devel`.

Comment: what if I'm using pre installed python on my mac?

Comment: @AdiyatMubarak You could then `brew reinstall python`.

Comment: @Algorithm_NL other than reinstalling Python using homebrew, is there another way?

Comment: had the same issue using python 3.8.8 which was installed via pyenv, upgraded to 3.8.15 which included the header files